# XAMPP Apache and MySQL services not starting or stopping after first installation

Tags: php, xampp

Hi I want to start learning PHP and MySql and also polish my knowledge of Javascript witch is very limited at the moment having only use jQuery and knowing only the core sintax of the language.I choose to read [Learning PHP MySQL and Javascript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596157134) witch seemed to fit all my needs.

Having always had bad luck when installing something new I immediately hit a dead end with XAMPP 1.7.7.

The server runs corectly when is first installed and I can stop MySQL and Apache from running from the control panel.But if close the control panel and reopen it I get and error.

If when it was first opened I left apache and Mysql opened I get the error  Apache Service not stopped [-1] the same goes for MySQL.If the services were close I get the same error that says apache service can't start same for MySQL.

I have tryed multiple instalations and the same thing happens.

I first tought I will install it and live them open so I can start working but sadly it didn't work corectly or I don't know how to run a PHP script corectly.

Here's what I did:

I opened PHPStorm and pasted this little scripped with a PHP extension :

```
  <?php

    echo "Hello world";

 ?>
```

After that I tried to run it but I get the error "PHP interpretor is not installed".
Shouldn't it have worked if the apache server was running?

Comment: What Operating System are you using? Is it is windows, try running as administrator.

Comment: i am using windows and running as administrator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should wait after you stopped apache or mysql to let them clean things up. If you want to force them to end their processes, you can kill **httpd.exe** and **mysqld.exe** from task manager and then try starting it from xampp control panel.

Comment: already did that and I get an error from windows that I can't stop it

Comment: try running apache_stop.bat and mysql_stop.bat in your XAMPP directory.

Comment: ...honestly nothing else worked for me...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are running Skype on the same machine? Its a known issue where Skype takes control over port 80 in order to become a supernode in the Skype network.

Go to Skype and in the `"Tools"` menu locate subsection `"Advanced"`, option `"Connection"`. There you'll find an option saying `"Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections"`. Uncheck it, click `"Save"` and try restarting your server.

Comment: I have skype installed but not running

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? Are you using the XAMPP control panel?

In windows press

```
Start
Run
Type "Services.msc"
Find the "Apache" service
Right click and stop
```

I find i get this error if i start the apache service without the control panel but try to stop it with the control panel.