# MySQL configuration issue with XAMPP 1.7.7 on Windows 7

Tags: xampp

Just downloaded the MySQL workbench for Windows and Just Installed XAMPP 1.7.7 but cannot get MySQL to start. I do realise its because MySQL is already using the port 3306 (it said as much) but how do i configure them correctly?

when i check the status after trying to switch MySQL on its returns 0:

> MySql started [Port 3306] XAMPP Applications Statue 1.1.2.2 httpd
>   state 1 Service 0 Start 0 Thread 0 OP 0 port 80 mysql state 0 Service
>   0 Start 0 Thread 0 OP 0 port 3306 ftp state 1 Service 0 Start 0 Thread
>   0 OP 0 port 21 mercurystate 0 Service 0 Start 0 Thread 0 OP 0 port 25
>   java state 0 Service 0 Start 0 Thread 0 OP 0 port 8080

I have also recently installed

I've tried following this thread and done what its suggested to no avail:

[XAMPP Apache and MySQL services not starting or stopping after first installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259737/xampp-apache-and-mysql-services-not-starting-or-stopping-after-first-installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this same exact issue before in Windows 7. To get MySQL to restart, try running the Windows services by going to start and typing "services" into the find box.

You'll need to open up the Component Services program, and then navigate to the "Services (Local)" folder. Find the "mysql" listing in the middle panel and then right click it and select "start" or "restart" to force it to run.

Workbench won't actually occupy port 3306 so it shouldn't be the cause of the problem.

In order to get Workbench to connect (yes, it's finicky at times), create a connection by going to tab Database -> Manage Connections.

Click on "New" and then fill in the following details:

```
Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)
Hostname: localhost
Port: 3306
Username: <whatever your XAMPP MySQL username is>
```

Click on "Test Connection" and you should get a prompt for the MySQL password. Hopefully, it should show that you can connect to the DB.

Good luck!